# UITableView on drag ended

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have a `UITableView` and need to know when the user's dragging ended? (when the user lifted his finger) I'm using Xamarin but an answer in Swift or objective-C would be fine.

EDIT

I tried this:

```
public class ImageSlideShowTable : UITableView, IUITableViewDelegate
{
    public event EventHandler DragEnded;

    public ImageSlideShowTable()
    {
        this.Delegate = this;
    }

    [Export("scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:")]
    public void DraggingEnded(UIScrollView scrollView, bool willDecelerate)
    {
        DragEnded?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    [Export("touchesEnded:touches:evt")]
    public override void TouchesEnded(Foundation.NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesEnded(touches, evt);

        // only gets called after I tap the screen
    }
}
```

But `DraggingEnded` never gets called and `TouchesEnded` only gets called after I tap the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. You need to override the `DraggingEnded` method in the `TableViewSource` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`UITableViewDelegate` inherits `UIScrollViewDelegate` so you can use `UIScrollView` protocol methods to get notified about dragging events:

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate;

Comment: I tried it but doesn't seem to be working (I edited my post)

Comment: @Darius Just to clarify: you want to know when user stoped dragging(took out his finger from the screen) or when the scrolling stopped. I recommend to try all UIScrollViewDelegate scrolling methods(print proper text to logs to check do they work in Xamarin)

Comment: when user stoped dragging(took out his finger from the screen). Ok I'll play around with it

Comment: I tried a bunch of things and didn't work...maybe this approach won't work in Xamarin

Comment: @Darius As a workaround can suggest you to add override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) to your ImageSlideShowTable

Comment: I left my office already, but I'm pretty sure I tried that and it only got called when I would tap the screen (no drag).

Comment: No, it is working for any touch event. Let me know does it work for you